# Gem installed and require but "Constant missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed the gem ['simple_uuid'](http://github.com/ryanking/simple_uuid) but nothing seems to be working.

Using irb and running the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple_uuid'
```

is fine, both return true. But running the following:

```
// Class added by simple_uuid
UUID.new
```

returns

```
NameError: uninitialized constant UUID
    from (irb):3
    from :0
```

I'm a ruby newbie, so don't assume much in the answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is inside a module SimpleUUID. So either do "include SimpleUUID" after the require, or refer to the class with the full namespace: SimpleUUID::UUID

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple_uuid'

> UUID.new
NameError: uninitialized constant UUID
        from (irb):3

> SimpleUUID::UUID.new
 => <UUID#70305762670060 time: Sat May 01 21:11:28 +0200 2010, usecs: 843284 jitter: 13605115058679102872>
```

Comment: So, gems aren't like .NET/Java name spaces?

Comment: No. A gem is a library which can include multiple classes and modules. Require includes a file, and the file can define whatever it wants. Usually this is driven by conventions (like most stuff in ruby).

I figured the module name by looking at the file: http://github.com/ryanking/simple_uuid/blob/master/lib/simple_uuid.rb

There you can see the class enclosed in "module". Modules are not just namespaces. I recommend you read about mixins in classes.

Comment: @Tom: you can work around this by doing `include SimpleUUID` to include it into the `main` workspace.

Comment: @Ryan_Bigg that's what I did in the end. This daft mismatch betweeen gems and namespaces is somewhat annoying. But RoR and Ruby are too powerful to ignore.